# Linux kernel module tcp connection

Tags: c, linux, ssl, tcp, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module which requires a tcp connection and it is really hard to find up-to-date manuals/examples/tutorials. I need the kernel module to be the client, to send and recive data and ssl encryption required too. Which of the dozen kernel tcp interfaces fits my needs and is the latest one?

Comment: Doing something like this in the kernel is probably not a good idea. I would recommend having the network communication in a user-space program that communicates with kernel module through some other means.

Comment: Are there any better options? I need somehow connect hardware simulator to kernel to test drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do such application (TCP/SSL) in user space and have a way to share buffer between userspace and kernel space to avoid copy overhead. Keep the kernel module processing simple and quick.